# code: 'ER_PARSE_ERROR',errno: 1064,sql: "UPDATE tasks SET WHERE id = '[object Object]'", sqlState: '42000',

Tags: react-native

Tengo un error al parecer es en SQL estoy con react-native y soy nuevo en ese campo, ese error me aparece cuando voy actualizar(PUT) el Post y Delete si funcionan.

error:
code: 'ER_PARSE_ERROR',
errno: 1064,
sql: "UPDATE tasks SET  WHERE id = '[object Object]'",
sqlState: '42000',
sqlMessage: "You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use
near 'WHERE id = '[object Object]'' at line 1"

codigo backend de Update:

```js
export const UpdateTasks = async(req, res) => {
    const connection = await connect();
     await connection.query("UPDATE tasks SET title=?,description=? WHERE id=?",[
        req.body.title,
        req.body.description,
        req.params.id,
    ]);
        
        res.sendStatus(204);
```

codigo frontend:

```js
export const updateTask = async(id, newTask) => {
    console.log(id, newTask)
     const res = await fetch(`${API}/${id}`, {
        method: "PUT",
        headers: {
            Accept: "application/json",
            "Content-Type": "application/json",
          },
          body: JSON.stringify(newTask),
   });
     return res;
```